# Install Ubuntu from iso file using grub2

Tags: installation, boot, grub2

I have previous versions of Ubuntu, which includes `grub2`. I see on the Internet that, `grub2` can boot from iso file, So, I booted Ubuntu from iso file, But whenever I tried to install, it gives an error that, "*The disk need to be unmounted first before install*".

My question is: **How can I install Ubuntu 12.04 from iso file using grub2?**

Comment: I would suggest you to go through this links [ISO Booting with Grub 2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549847), [link 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z35zyDpMIMM),[link 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hnCXc2ZEys&feature=related). Also read `oldfred` post in [Install Ubuntu from GRUB2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1984994)

Comment: What OS do you have right now?

Comment: grub2 is runnig, that's why you can't install ^^ . he runs the ISO, and the grub2 partition/s are running, which is/are your installed Ubuntu partition/s. So you have to install from a USB or a Disk, then the Disk or the USB are the "mounted" partition, so you'll be able to install (:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have successfully booted from iso file and install from that iso file!

### The procedure is here

- First put your Ubuntu iso file in a partition, I have put that in "NTFS" partition, But it should work with `ext4` partition also. It is second partition in my hard disk. 
  For example, let's name our Ubuntu iso file as `ubuntu.iso`. the partition is `/dev/sda2` in my case. The location of the Ubuntu iso file is now in `(hd0,2)/ubuntu.iso` as seen by grub2, i.e It is in the root of the second partition
- Then reboot your system, containing grub2.
- Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to bring the grub2 menu, if it is not shown by default.
- In the grub2 menu, press <kbd>C</kbd> to bring *Command Prompt* of the grub2.
- In the command prompt type this one by one, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each line.

  ```
  loopback loop (hd0,2)/ubuntu.iso
  linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu.iso quiet splash --
  initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
  boot
  ```

In 2nd command, if **vmlinuz** doesn't work use **vmlinuz.efi** .

After typing `boot` press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The Live Ubuntu system will be started.

- Open a terminal and type the below command to unmount the drive where iso file resides

  ```
  sudo umount -l /isodevice
  ```
- Then proceed with the normal installation procedure.

#### Notes:

1. If you put your iso file in a partition other than 2nd partition, change `(hd0,2)` to `(hd0,X)`, where X refers to the partition number.
2. If you put your iso file in a USB pendrive, and you start grub2 from Hard disk *(installed by your previous system)* , change `(hd0,2)` accordingly. If you have only one partition in the pendrive, it will be `(hd1,1)`. here `hd1` refers to the pen drive.
3. I have tested this method for installing Ubuntu in `ext4` and `jfs` partition, they worked. But installation in `btrfs` partition failed.

Comment: It helps me a lot

Comment: @vanabel glad to hear this, especially for one your answers that doesn't get much attention :)