# If I cannot boot from CD or USB, how do I install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

Not able to install ubuntu from USB or CD. I have ubuntu 12.04 installed but I have to reformat my laptop. Neither CD nor USB boots. I want something like that can help me boot.

Comment: Download Ubuntu again, and burn it to CD.  Do an [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM/) on the ISO file first.

Comment: Does it give you any error messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/915/is-it-possible-to-install-without-a-cd-or-usb-drive

Comment: [This question](http://askubuntu.com/q/157055/61218) may help you, If you have the iso file and grub2. but I am not sure, about whether it is possible to complete formatting of laptop

Comment: You do know you have to set your BIOS to boot from CD-drive first (before the internal HDD)?

Comment: Are you saying your laptop used to be able to boot from CD's and USB flash drives, but is no longer capable of doing so? Or are you saying that you're specifically having trouble burning an Ubuntu CD or writing an Ubuntu USB flash drive that is bootable?

Answer (score 0):

That's easy:

1. Remove your hard disk drive from your laptop.
2. Connect your laptop's hard drive to another computer (desktop or
   laptop) using any method: direct connector (laptops), sata or pata
   cable, usb-to-sata/pata adaptor,etc. This computer should be able to boot from CD/DVD/USB.
3. You must observe that your laptop's hard disk drive must be the only
   one connected to the computer, this is needed in order to get a grub
   clean with just the Ubuntu OS mentioned on it at the boot.
4. Install Ubuntu.
5. When finished, just shut the computer down the normal way. Don't
   restart.
6. With the computer turned off, remove the hard disk drive and connect
   it again in the hard disk drive bay of your laptop.
7. Boot, be patience, the system may delay booting in a different
   computer.
8. And enjoy.

This process has been tested both in laptops and desktops and the result is a fresh install fully and successfully working.

*Step 3 is very important as if you have another OS installed in a local drive the GRUB will notice and record it to be mentioned in the GRUB's options. Additionally, your GRUB can be written in a different hard disk drive. To avoid these issues simply disconnect all the hard disk drives and maintain only the one where you wish your OS to be installed.*

I hope this help you.

Good luck!