# Install ubuntu using GRUB2

Tags: installation, boot, grub2

I have Deepin linux installed and now I need to install ubuntu. I don't have CD ROM , so I thought I can use GRUB2 ISO boot option. I have used the link [Install Ubuntu from iso file using grub2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157055/install-ubuntu-from-iso-file-using-grub2) to boot ISO using GRUB2. I need to install the operating system. When I click Install Ubuntu icon in desktop, the installer starts. But I can't see the option where we can specify the partition. It just directly goes to installing. Even if I click install, the installer does nothing and the installation didn't start. What to do? Any ideas?

Comment: FeldAP1 - you tried to respond to an answer by adding another answer.  The way we respond is by editing your question with additional information.  Since you appear to have multiple accounts, please register one of these accounts.  Then click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request that your unregistered accounts are merged.  Once done, you will be able to re-edit your question with further details.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to keep Deepin Linux, an easier and standard way of doing this is to create a live USB disk. As long your computer is not old (not more than a few years old), your computer should be able to boot from the USB disk. To create a live USB disk, [download UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/unetbootin-linux-latest), run it and select Ubuntu as the distribution and the version, or if you have the disk image downloaded enter the path in the text field at the bottom. Then go through the wizard and let it do its job.