# Ubuntu from .iso freezes

Tags: grub2, freeze

I have followed [these](https://askubuntu.com/a/157112) steps to boot Ubuntu from an .iso I have on a pendrive. I am able to start booting, but it freezes during the boot prosedure.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hso3u.jpg) are the last boot logs(?). The cursor does not blink.

I have seen this, but I was unable to get the 32bit version of Ubuntu.

Comment: For 20.04 use `initrd (loop)/casper/initrd` not `initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz`

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I have, since initrd.lz was not there so thats what I assumed was required, sorry for not clarifying

Comment: Have you tried the USB on a different computer? checked the MD55SUM? Some other reasons: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot

Comment: I think it may be number 5. from that list. This usb has a lot of un related files and also is formated with msdos